# text box does not show the error 

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datetime, date

I am trying to validate two data of birth text box fields if the member does not enter  in 
these two boxes an error message will popped out like "pls enter valid date format"

by using the following code

```
       if (tbStartDate.Text != "0" && tbEndDate.Text != "0")
       { 

        string dob = tbStartDate.Text;
        DateTime dv = DateTime.Parse(dob);
        string format1 = dv.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string dob2 = tbEndDate.Text;
        DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(dob2);
        string format2 = dt2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     }
      else
     {
            MessageBox.Show("pls enter valid date ");

     }
```

when i am trying to save with out entering the  textbox values it was showing  error like this 
  "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime".

can any one help on this....

this is modified code still it was showing error at Datetime DV;

```
         private void btnCTimetablessave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string dob = tbStartDate.Text;
        DateTime dv;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dob, out dv))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("pls enter a valid  start date");
            return;
        }

        string format1 = dv.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string dob2 = tbEndDate.Text;
        DateTime dt2;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dob2, out dt2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("pls enter valid end date");
            return;
        }

        string format2 = dt2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

still it was showing error like this   "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" at datetime Dv;

and this is modified code third time

```
       private void btnCTimetablessave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         string dob = tbStartDate.Text;
        DateTime dv;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dob, out dv))
        {

            MessageBox.Show("pls enter a valid  start date");
            return ;
        }

        string format1 = dv.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string dob2 = tbEndDate.Text;
        DateTime dt2;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(dob2, out dt2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("pls enter valid end date");
            return;
        }

        string format2 = dt2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because an empty textbox returns an empty string when you access the Text property and  DateTime.Parse() will throw that exception if passed an empty string.

Comment: it was the version problem when i am executing this one there is other code something is executed in back ground , I have corrected that one and i have tried  all these techniques, all working are fine ... many thanks ......to all

Answer (score 5):

Don't use DateTime.Parse. Use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) instead. The result is a boolean value that returns true if the parsing was successfully.

**Update**
As requested in your comment:

```
DateTime dv;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(dob,out dv)){
   MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid date");
   return;
}
....
```

Cleary, you also can use Parse and catch the exception, but this would be bad style. Better to use TryParse. I have only checked for one date value. You can extend the logic for your needs. Hope this helped.

Comment: dear hcl still it was showing error i have included the modified code

Comment: @user6824127: The extended code you have posted looks good to me. Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" at datetime Dv;

Comment: @user6824127: I have copied your modified code into Visual Studio and it works as expected. Check if you call really the above method. Probably you have a duplicate that will be called.

Comment: In database i have added  "date" datatype for start date and end date fields instead of varchar

Comment: @user6824127: If I understand you right, the error you get is now from the insertion/update code. Right?

Comment: When converting to string to date time, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the date time object , 
Make sure your method arguments are in right format..
string was not recognised as a valid date time   these are errors and trouble shooting tips it was showing

Comment: @user6824127: Sorry, I can not help anymore. There must be some other code that is executing, not showed in your example. Or maybe I'm overviewing something very obvious, but I don't think so. I have checked your modified version (I think it was the second version) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check using `string.IsNullOrEmpty(tbStartDate.Text)` whether its blank or not.

I would recommend using a `DatetimePicker` for selecting the date's which will return you a valid `DateTime` value which you can use for further processing

Comment: still it was showing error  like this    String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Datetime.TryParse like this

```
if(!DateTime.TryParse(dob))
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `try catch block` to catch `FormatException` so that if user doesn't enter date in proper format it will catch the exception and give message of your choice

```
try
{
    string dob = tbStartDate.Text;
    DateTime dv = DateTime.Parse(dob);
    string format1 = dv.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string dob2 = tbEndDate.Text;
    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(dob2);
    string format2 = dt2.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}
catch (System.FormatException)
{
    MessageBox.Show("pls enter valid date format");
}
```

**OR**

using  `DateTimePicker` is Always a better and user friendly approach